# Angular: HTTP post request error "grant_type parameter is missing" when requesting access token from Spotify

Tags: angular, http, post, authorization, access-token

I'm trying to get an access token from Spotify so I can then retrieve publicly available information (tracks, albums, etc.) but when I make the POST request, the response comes back telling me that the grant_type is missing  Here's the code I'm working with:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

//clientId and clientSecret declared up here

tokenUrl: string = "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token";
idAndSecret: string = btoa(this.clientId + ":" + this.clientSecret);

constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

body = {
    'grant_type': "client_credentials",
};

options = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Authorization': 'Basic '.concat(this.idAndSecret),
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    })
};

getAccessToken(): string{
    this.httpClient.post(this.tokenUrl, this.body, this.options).subscribe(
        response => {
            console.log(response);
        }
    );

    return this.token;
}
```

The HttpErrorResponse comes back with status: 400 and error: {error: unsupported grant_type, error_description: grant_type parameter is missing}

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue, and fixed it by replacing the body object with the following string:
'grant_type=client_credentials'. So in your case it would be:

```
body = 'grant_type=client_credentials';
```

I don't know why it worked this way, but not with an object.